# How to set conditional statement for image in Flutter?

Tags: image, dart, conditional-statements, flutter, assets

I have conditional statement to set image from Flutter assets, but is not working in Scaffold body.

How to set conditional statement for image in Flutter?

```
String _backgroundImage;

void _setImage() {
  String _mTitle = "${widget.title.data}";

  if(_mTitle == “Goodmorrning”) {
    _backgroundImage = "assets/mobil_hello/goodmorrning.jpg";
  } else if(_mTitle == “Good day”) {
    _backgroundImage = "assets/mobil_hello/goodday.jpg";
  } 

  print("_mTitle: $_mTitle");  // works
  print("_backgroundImage: $_backgroundImage"); // works
}


Widget build(BuildContext contest) {

  return Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.backgroundColor,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: new AssetImage("$_backgroundImage") // not working
                        ),
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to call setState in setImage

Comment: If you are using `statefullwidget` then. if(_mTitle == “Goodmorrning”) {
 setState((){
    _backgroundImage = "assets/mobil_hello/goodmorrning.jpg";
});
  }
  same for `elseif` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String _setImage() {
  String _mTitle = "${widget.title.data}";

  if(_mTitle == “Goodmorrning”) {
    return "assets/mobil_hello/goodmorrning.jpg";
  } else if(_mTitle == “Good day”) {
    return "assets/mobil_hello/goodday.jpg";
  } 

  print("_mTitle: $_mTitle");  // works
  print("_backgroundImage: $_backgroundImage"); // works
}


Widget build(BuildContext contest) {

  return Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.backgroundColor,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: new AssetImage(_setImage()) // not working
                        ),
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, You created void _setImage() method which returns nothing,and also you can not use it like this  **new AssetImage(_setImage())** ,So You have to make method like String _setImage() ,which returns String (_backgroundImage), so you can directly call this method in new AssetImage(_setImage()).

**Replace your code with Below Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    String _backgroundImage;
    String _setImage() {
      String _mTitle = "${widget.title.data}";

      if(_mTitle == "Goodmorrning") {
        _backgroundImage = "assets/mobil_hello/goodmorrning.jpg";
      } else if(_mTitle == "Good day") {
        _backgroundImage = "assets/mobil_hello/goodday.jpg";
      }
      print("_mTitle: $_mTitle");  
      print("_backgroundImage: $_backgroundImage");
      return _backgroundImage; // here it returns your _backgroundImage value

    }


    Widget build(BuildContext contest) {

      return Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.backgroundColor,
            image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: new AssetImage(_setImage()) //call your method here
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```